# "partitions" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) tag is described as follows:

- Questions related to the different ways of expressing an integer as a sum of integers; or, questions related to the subdivision of the edge or vertex set of a (hyper)graph.

Why are those two topics put together?  If this is supposed to be about either partitions of a number or partitions of a set, then why only that one narrow instance of partitions of a set?

**Later edit:** Since writing the above I scanned down the list of questions bearing this tag, and consequently edited the description to read as follows:

- Questions related to the different ways of expressing an integer as a sum of integers; or, questions related to the subdivision of a set into smaller disjoint sets;
  questions related to the subdivision of an interval into smaller intervals that intersect only at the endpoints.

Comment: My *guess* would be that the tag description was written *after the fact* by examining the questions tagged partitions. In other words, most likely that slightly strange tag description was "descriptive" instead of "prescriptive", unlike many of our other tags.

Comment: I'm working on a question concerning compositions (i.e., ordered partitions) of n, and notice that there's not a 'compositions of n' tag. Also, I have previously asked a question regarding cyclic compositions of n. Should I create a 'compositions of n' tag?

Comment: @DanMoore : If there is to be such a tag, I might call it "compositions of an integer".  But my guess is it's too narrow a topic for its own tag.  How many questions would bear that tag?

Comment: @MichaelHardy One existing question about the count of cyclic compositions, and one future question featuring the reversal of a composition - i.e., a composition in the reverse order as another. So, both questions relate to ordered partitions rather than unordered partitions. I think there are other questions relating to ordered partitions as well.

Comment: Do you think that it is inappropriate to include compositions and cyclic compositions within the "partitions" tag? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No, I think the partitions tag is OK for this.

Comment: @DanMoore : In that case it sounds as if everybody lived happily ever after.